# Actions on Google - How can I display a table?

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, google-assist-api

The Google Assistant can currently do this but I'm not sure if there is a way to display a clean table with the [Actions on Google](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses) library. I would like to reproduce a table similar to what is displayed in the following screenshot:
[image]

This doesn't look like any of the components that are available in the library.

Would it be possible to achieve this with a BasicCard and Lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else with the same question, [Google recently announced consumer availability of rich responses optimized for Smart Displays](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/designing-for-google-assistant-on-smart_26.html?utm_source=dev_newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=july_2018). As of 7/26/2018, you can now have responses with [table cards](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/rich-responses#table_cards).

Answer (score 1):

The exact UI above is not currently possible using the 3P components. You can use similar widgets like a list or carousel to get close to the UI above, or render the whole thing as an image and return as a card.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer, looks like I may need to render the table as an image.

Comment: I noticed that the UI for the transactions order contains a very similar table to the one in the screenshot. Is it also possible to modify the open source client library and develop a custom table component?

Comment: No it wouldn't be as the widgets are not built in the library but rather get rendered by the Assistant.